# Workaround for Mavericks Bluetooth/Wi-Fi interference?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

I have [this problem](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23561100#23561100): I normally have Bluetooth enabled so I can make use of my speaker system and Magic Trackpad on my [mid-2012 11" MacBook Air](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp650) (2.0 GHz i7, 8GB).

However, when it's enabled, Wi-Fi association does not complete well, either on boot or wake from sleep.  In my case, the Wi-Fi icon in the menu bar oscillates a bit and generally gives up.  Clicking the icon again may or may not show my network; if it does, I can click it and it will usually associate, though occasionally it complains that association failed.  This happens on all networks I regularly use—one, a Buffalo AP, the other, a Linksys.

If I turn Bluetooth off, I can associate just as quickly as I ever have with no issues.  I generally don't even see it trying to associate; it's done before I'm logged in.

This appears to be a Mavericks problem, as the folks in the linked Apple discussion are speculating.  I know I never had it under ML.  Unfortunately, I *don't* know exactly when I started having the issue, but it seems like it became prevalent around the time I bought the Magic Trackpad.  This seems odd, though, since the Trackpad is tens of miles away on one of the networks I'm having issues with.

Is there a workaround that would allow me to leave Bluetooth enabled so I can much more easily use my Trackpad?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After digging in the aforementioned Apple discussion, I discovered at one point that an Apple technician recommended to one of the participants that they should remove their `com.apple.Bluetooth` property list.  I did so:

```
$ sudo rm /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth.plist
```

and rebooted.  When the reboot was complete, Wi-Fi was working flawlessly with Bluetooth on.  I lost pairings to all my Bluetooth devices except my Magic Trackpad.  I added back my speakers and all remains well 24+ hours later.

**UPDATE:** Adding my portable speaker seems to have been the straw that broke the camel's back.  Had to repeat these steps and then leave it unpaired to keep Wi-Fi working.

Comment: Interesting, I've just fixed this on my rMBP after the mavericks update. But not reconnected my speaker yet, which speaker do you have?

Comment: HMDX JAM (one of the original run, looks like.)

Comment: Nope, it didn't do much for me. My problem is with the PS4 controller. As soon as I turn it on the WiFi goes ballistic. bad latency (lost pings) and download speed down to a crawl.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this problem for 2,5 days (MBPr, magic mouse). My wifi signal dropped on occasion. When I put my MBPr close to the Airport Extreme (so when the wifi signal was very strong), this problem did not occur. Deleting the Bluetooth prefs file made no difference. I found out eventually that Bluetooth interfered with the wifi signal. The solution: use 5Ghz only for your Wifi. Bluetooth uses 2.4 Ghz so no interference anymore. [Airport Utility: wireless: wireless options: click and name your 5GHz network name]

Comment: This may work for some people, but I still don't have 5GHz Wi-Fi at home—2.4GHz only—and I haven't had this problem in some time.